# Vertical centering of text inside tabular does not work as expected

Tags: tables, minted

I have a simple table with three columns.  The second and third columns contain minted environments, and the first column contains text that should be vertically centered for each row.  I'm using the array package `m` and `t` specifiers, but they are not working as I (naively) expect them to.  Basically, the text in the first column is always shown top-aligned instead of centered.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{m{0.2\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}}
\toprule
& \textbf{Alpha} & \textbf{Beta} \\
\midrule
\textbf{One} &
\begin{minted}{text}
Testing1
Testing2
\end{minted}
&
\begin{minted}{text}
Testing3
Testing4
\end{minted}
\\
\textbf{Two} &
\begin{minted}{text}
Testing5
Testing6
\end{minted}
&
\begin{minted}{text}
Testing7
Testing8
\end{minted}
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

What am I missing and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`m` doesn't align the entry with the centre of the other columns It aligns the centre of *this* entry with the alignment point of the other columns (which is at the top as you used `p`).

Change all three entries to `m`.